# How do I remove the background from an image?

Tags: gimp, image-editing, microsoft-paint

I have a logo:

[image: my logo]

and I'd like to get rid of that yellow-ish background once and for all and perhaps even change the whole logo to black instead of green. is there a way to accomplish this with Paint or GIMP?

I imagine getting rid of the corners is simple, but what about the inside?

Comment: If you don't have a higher resolution it's going to be difficult. Do you have one?

You have an uneven background so there are lots of little differences and the arabic characters on the bottom are quite small. You'll have artifacts that intertwine the background and foreground. Use the selection tool, zoom in pretty far and remove what you can. There won't be a magic button for it from what I can tell.

Comment: I agree, there is no magic button to do this. If you want to use either Paint or Gimp, I'd suggest Gimp because it supports transparency, where Paint does not. Personally I would use Photoshop to do this, I'd suggest selecting the green letters and copying them to a new layer.

Comment: Remaking the log seems like a better idea, if are able to retype the text that is. Doing this in any editing software that supports transparency is pretty easy, just use the circle tool, give it a stroke/border, make the colour empty, and use the type tool to write along the edge on the path. This would be the easiest in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/132871) on GraphicDesign.SE explains how to achieve this in GIMP with "Filters>Enhance>Wavelet decompose" and "Colors>Curves...". However, probably instead of "Colors>Curves...", the saturation should better be adjust with one of "Colors>Saturation" or some other tool in "Colors" menu.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In GIMP you can convert the image to black and white. It's a feature called  *Desaturate*.

[image]

Now that you have it in B&W then increase Brightness and Contrast in a way that the background becomes bright white and the letters are deep dark.

[image]

just like these example:

[image]

In that state will be easy to select all the white color with this tool

[image]

Be sure that the threshold of selection is near to zero to select only a single color and select *feather edges*.

[image]

Add a transparent layer (`Layers > Transparency > Add Alpha Channel`)

Clear (`Edit > Clear or Del`) the selected color and you will have a transparent background.

If you want to have a new background, add a Layer and put the color in the new layer.

Comment: I've done exactly this with `GraphicConverter` (MacOS only).  Note: once you're down to pure black and pure white, it's easy to do a color-replace to set either background or the object to a desired color.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise vectorising the logo with Inkscape. Open Inkscape, select `File > Import...` to import the logo, select `Path > Trace Bitmap...` to trace the logo to a vector, adjust the settings to create a clean vector (tick the `Live Preview` checkbox to see how your final vector will look) and click `OK` when you're happy with the settings. The vectorised logo will be placed over the bitmap logo, so move it out of the way and delete the original bitmap from the Inkscape file. Save the Inkscape file (the format is `.svg`, for a vector graphic file).

As this is a vector graphic, you can now easily change the colours, style of the lines, and shape of the logo, and can export it at different sizes and resolutions without it appearing blurry or pixelated.

Comment: I agree, with a vector it's much easier to work the contours back into a more smooth shape from a low-resolution source image.

Answer (score 2):

With [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) use Brightness/Contrast like this:

[image: Paint.NET Brightness/Contrast]

If you need it transparent, use the wand with 0% tolerance and flood mode global, click on a white region and then press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the white background.

[image: Paint.NET wand global flood]

Answer (score 1):

I saved your image and opened in Gimp.  I used the Select by Color tool with a threshold of about 125.  I selected the dark green in the center letters.  I copied it and pasted into a new image.  Saved as xcf and exported as png.  There's some pixelation (this is not a vector approach as described by others) and the shading around the medium sized text that looks like (forgive me for this) Chinese characters is not clean.  Otherwise I think it's ok.

Here's the png:

[image: Islamic Logo]

Edit: Just realized that the "Shandong" means that they probably ARE Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Paint by saving it as a low-quality Bitmap-image. You should click on File>Save As and then select `Monochrome Bitmap`, `16 Color Bitmap` or `256 Color Bitmap` as file types. Doing this makes there be fewer colors in the image that can be used and therefore changes the colors to the closest of these colors. Which format you should choose depends on the image, in your case using 16-color bitmap would give this:

[image]

I admit, like that it doesn't look so nice, but there are several easy ways to fix it so that it looks nicer:

Since there are very few colors, you can easily use the fill tool to change the green to gray for example. You can also use the eraser to remove the gray spots in the background.

Or if you want it to go even faster, you can totally replace a color with another by selecting the color you want to replace as color 2, cutting out the whole image with CTRL+A and CTRL+X, filling it with the color you want to replace with and pasting the image with the "transparent selection" option activated.

In your image, after replacing (192; 192; 192) gray with white and (0; 128; 128) green with (128; 128; 128) gray, it gives this result:

[image]